# VUEJS 2, how to bind events to dynamic html at runtime

Tags: vuejs2

I have datatable which is created through columns and items array.
I want to create one anchor link in vuejs which will call component method on click. Also in the items array may be contains html which i want to bind to vuejs events.

Thanks.

Comment: Which vue datatable component are you using?

Comment: I am using bootstrap datatable for this. not vue component.